# Spring transactions on recursive calls

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I have a method that starts a transaction programmatically using transaction template from Spring.

```
Void methodA() {
    TransactionTmeplate..........

    Setpropgation to requires new....

    /// do my stuff in trasaction


}
```

So if I have another class which calls this method it creates a transaction, as I would expect. But what happens if this method is entered again from the same calling thread. Does another transaction get created?

Example:

```
MethodCaller -> methodA (transaction created) -> methodD -> methodA(??)
```

Following on:

Also if class is `@autowired`, would two calling threads ever share the same transaction, considering one instance exists?

I would assume not as they have there own own entry on the stack for the method.

Comment: What sort of logic would accomplish something like this? A transaction is supposed to be a single peice of logic. I would say this has code smell

Comment: yes i agree... but  im trying to follow some code and the behaviour... seems like this... and since im writing it again... i want to be sure about transactions and how they work... whats possible what is not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javadoc on [`Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html#REQUIRES_NEW) is pretty clear, I am not sure whether it could be better explained.

As for the different threads calling your method: the `TransactionManager` will make sure that threads won't interleave with each other regarding transactions.

But having a method that is re-entrant and always starts a new transaction indicates that your application is not properly layered. Try to do some refactoring, and make sure that the method responsibile for starting a new transaction never gets called recursively.